# An idea that attracts pursuit by many but that is actually a bad idea with no solution

Tags: idiom-requests

An idea that attracts pursuit by many but that is actually a bad idea with no solution.

An idea bomb?  mind suck?  time waster (lame)?    idea siren?

It comes up for me in software development/tech when we think we're smarter than we really are because we've think we've thought of something that doesn't exist or at least hasn't gone mainstream.  There seem to be a lot of benefits to it but it takes a significant investment in time (at least) to realize how the idea wasn't as great as we thought it was.  I feel like I've heard a good phrase for this podcasted/blogged about but I can't think of it now.

Comment: The historical idiom is *squaring the circle* and the people who do it *circle squarers*. See also *perpetuum mobile* and *trisecting the angle*.

Comment: This is probably not the best place to discover a phrase that was recently blogged/podcasted.

Comment: How about "the Internet"?

Comment: Ah, the wall against which so many heads have been beaten.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for

> **snipe hunt**: Based on a prank where people are sent out to chase down a bird that isn't actually out there; metaphorically a search for something of ambiguous qualities that does not actually exist.

Although the derivation is different, this has echoes of the XKCD-invented "sport" of "nerd sniping", where someone is presented with a problem so fascinating that they lose all concentration on everything else.

It does, however, have connotations of being a deliberate practical joke.  Similar idioms without that connotation are "wild goose chase" and "fool's errand".

Answer (score 2):

a **flight(s) of fancy**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+flight+of+fancy)  idiom

> an imaginative but unrealistic idea

As in:

His proposed solutions to problems were filled with flights of fancy.

Answer (score 1):

"Will-o-the-wisp" would work in many contexts.

"Will-o-the-wisp: a person or thing that is difficult or impossible to find, reach or catch." New Oxford American Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

**Chimera**

> 1a capitalized : a fire-breathing she-monster in Greek mythology having a lion's head, a goat's body, and a serpent's tail
>   b : an imaginary monster compounded of incongruous parts
>   2 : an illusion or fabrication of the mind
>   **especially : an unrealizable dream**

Chimera: Merriam Webster online

*Chimera* might be confusing in the software environment since it is the name for a database software and also a term for an FEA meshing strategy. You would probably want to disambiguate it the first time.

**ignis fatuus**

> 1 : a light that sometimes appears in the night over marshy ground and is often attributable to the combustion of gas from decomposed organic matter
>   2 : **a deceptive goal or hope**

Ignis fatuus: Merriam Webster online

> But he was slow – painfully slow, hour after hour slow, sweating and struggling in front of his own class slow – to accept the truth about the simple statement: the truth being that it is an **ignis fatuus**.

2007, Clive James, Cultural Amnesia, Picador 2007, p. 805:

> ... is indispensable in these United States. The necessity arises from the extent both of territory and population. He knew that the popular current was running strongly against the principle of intermediate elections and that an attempt was making in this country to throw all governmental duties in relation to elections upon the people in their individual capacity. This is visionary and impracticable. A mere **ignis fatuus** and calculated to be onerous on the people whom it is intended to benefit. He was satisfied that the people could not beneficially exercise this right to its full extent in a great extended populous community and therefore he thought it was for them in certain cases to delegate it to their legislative representatives.

Proceedings and Debates of the Virginia State Convention of 1829-1830

Answer (score 0):

I have been hearing [rabbit hole](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+down+the+rabbit+hole) quite a lot lately. It’s originally from *Alice in Wonderland* but it seems to be gaining a new life.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the **Sunk Cost Fallacy** and is well documented, especially in the software industry! Reading your description I immediately related to similar frustrating projects I’d worked on in software development :)

[[Wikipedia: Sunk Cost]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_cost)

Here’s a passage from an article related to software development and the sunk cost fallacy, covers your description pretty well I think!

> The **sunk cost fallacy**, also known as the Concorde fallacy, is a very interesting phenomenon. What it basically boils down to is the fact that it is human nature to throw good money after bad. The more resources (time, money) we invest in something, the more likely we are to stick with it despite all the indicators of our venture being a failure
>
> It is therefore no big surprise that when it comes to software development, we’re not immune. Infact we take the sunk cost fallacy to new heights of awesome :).
>
> Article Link: [[Software Development and the sunk cost fallacy]](https://skorks.com/2010/04/software-development-and-the-sunk-cost-fallacy/)

Here’s another more recent article:

[[TIME: The sunk cost fallacy is ruining your decions. Here’s How.]](http://time.com/5347133/sunk-cost-fallacy-decisions/)

I’d also recommend reading into the very related [[software development death march]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_march_(project_management)). Good luck!